# ASP.NET MVC, Cancel triggering Client Validation, Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor, .NET 4.5

I have a required field value.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

rendered as :

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="* Required" id="Name" name="Name" style="width:440px" type="text" value="" />
```

Unfortunately it being triggered by the Cancel button, although buttons defined as:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@style="width:440px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

    <p class="form-buttons">
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="Save">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </p>

}
```

Also it seems to be triggered pre Post Action, so must be via Javascript.

I do not mind JS triggering the validation, but I do need to ensure that the Cancel button just closes the page and returns to another page as handled by the post action if btn != Save.

So how do I stop this Cancel validation please?

Comment: add a class of cancel to the cancel button, that prevents validation being triggered.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a *submit* button send data to the server if it's just going to ignore it.  The best practice is to use a hyperlink (`@Html.ActionLink()`) as the Cancel button, not a form submitting button.

Comment: Thanks. Both good points